# Wordpress: javascript not loading after enqueuing in function.php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently i m transfering my site to wordpress and while doing it i m enqueuing javascripts in my wordpress footer through function,php but it not loading in browser .

my function.php codes :

```
function NewBiz_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array ('jquery'), NULL ,true);
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/animate/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-min',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/animate/animate.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js-bundle' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',array(),NULL,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js-min' . get_stylesheet_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',NULL,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('counterup' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/counterup/counterup.js', NULL, NULL ,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/easing/easing.js', NULL, NULL ,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing.min' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/easing/easing.min.js' , NULL,NULL , true);
    wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome.min'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style ('ionicons' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style ('ionicons.min' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('mobile-nav' . get_template_directory_uri () . '/lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js',NULL, NULL , true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',array () ,NULL ,NULL ,true );
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_migrate' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js',array() ,NULL ,NULL ,true );



}   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'NewBiz_scripts' );
?>

<?php
$theme_name_images = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/';
?>
```

only main.js is loading rest not loading .

[image: screenshot DOM]

please some one can help me to figure out what i m doing wrong i new to wordpress.
thankyou.

Comment: can you please tell me where you added this code In child theme or parent theme ?

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar i added this code to parent theme. Actually i m converting a html site to wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is already inside WordPress so you don't need to add jQuery again and if you are including minified version `.min` then you don't need to include the full version. I have commented the repeating files. You also made a mistake enqueue where you added `.` instead of `,` I have edited your code so try this code. It should work.

```
function NewBiz_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array ('jquery'), NULL ,true);
//    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/animate/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate-min',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/animate/animate.min.css' );
//    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min',get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js-bundle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',array ('jquery'),NULL,true);
//    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',array ('jquery'),true);
    wp_enqueue_script('counterup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/counterup/counterup.js', array ('jquery'), NULL ,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/easing/easing.js', array ('jquery'), NULL ,true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/easing/easing.min.js' , array ('jquery'),NULL , true);
//    wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');
    wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css');
//    wp_enqueue_style ('ionicons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style ('ionicons-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('mobile-nav', get_template_directory_uri () . '/lib/mobile-nav/mobile-nav.js',array ('jquery'), NULL , true);
//    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',array () ,NULL ,NULL ,true );
//    wp_enqueue_script('jquery_migrate' . get_template_directory_uri() . '/lib/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js',array() ,NULL ,NULL ,true );



}   

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'NewBiz_scripts' );
?>

<?php
$theme_name_images = get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/img/';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have wp_footer hook called in your theme template?

```
wp_footer();
```

it's usually located in the theme footer.php it's required by WordPress wp_enqueue_script because otherwise the place to add the scripts to would be missing.

Best,
Sebo